# Position down all the scroll in ionic 3

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic3

I'm creating a chat and my problem is that the div that has the messages inside it I put a scroll, but I can not keep it under everything.

This is the view code and styles:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12>
            <button ion-button block color="success" style="text-transform: none" (click)="seeMembers()">See members</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-12 class="div_chat" #div_theme>
            <ion-list insert>
              <button ion-item>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
              </button>
            </ion-list>
            <h3 *ngIf="themeDB == false" text-center><strong>There are no new Topics</strong></h3>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

This is my stylesheet

```
page-see-theme{
  .div_chat{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

}
```

Any idea is very useful, thanks for your help

Comment: what do you mean by "under everything? z-index or vertically?

Comment: try adding `position: relative; top: 0`...top 0 if u want it to stick to the button above it

Comment: The higher div and the position is for the div?

Comment: I want the scroll to appear initially below everything, is it understandable?

Comment: It did not work to put the top and position. Modify the div, that is, the position of the div